# Differences between two dates

Tags: java, date

Consider the code below. I'm calculating the differences in days between two dates. However, the output is sometimes invalid. Does anyone know how this could be? Don't be concerned about leap years.

```
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")           
Date date1 = (Date) myFormat.parse(datenow);
Date date2 = (Date) myFormat.parse(factuurdatumList.get(i));
long difference = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
System.out.println("Days: " + TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(difference, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
int openstaand = (int) TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(difference, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: what are the inputs and the outputs and what it should be ?

Comment: *"output is sometimes invalid"* In what way? Show example. But I'll bet that the invalid output is caused by dates crossing a Daylight Savings Time transition.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a question that is answerable?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions so you will be better prepared and able to ask a question that will be well received and more importantly **answerable**.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

***Update:*** Changed day and month to allow single digit, and added example dates and output.

Easy enough, if you stop using the old out-dated `Date` class.

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-M-uuuu");
LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse("23-6-2018", fmt);
LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse("23-12-2018", fmt);
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2);
System.out.println("Days: " + days);
```

*Output*

```
Days: 183
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/9lfC7e).

Comment: gives DataTimeParseException , it can't parse 23-6-2018 ?? Does only changing it to d-M-uuuu works? In other words, will it also take 23-12 then?

Comment: it does not work?

Comment: for some reason days return a DATE for me? WTF?

Comment: @NotDutch No idea what you're doing. Updated answer to show how it works.

Comment: I see what the problem is. It outputs the days as a negative number:P Which i know is the same for the new class, but if youre calculating stuff with it..

Comment: Used Math.abs and it worked man, thanks:)